# Is it possible to change "recommended Items"?

Tags: league-of-legends

I recognized some items which are listed as `recommended` in the shop menu are pretty useless for certain champion builds and it is better to get some other instead.

Because I am pretty new to LoL I find myself clicking through the shop menu for minutes, wasting time searching for items my friends recommended to me, which all could be spent farming or fighting.

**Is there a way to change the list of recommended items for each champion?** And if that is the case, is it possible to show more than one set of items for different Champion builds (like more focused on DPS or AP on Kog'Maw)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of patch 3.7, May 2013, [the game now officially supports item sets](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/news/customize-your-build-client-item-sets).  You can define sets of items in the launcher, and use these in-game at the shop.

You can define multiple sets, multiple categories per set, and any number of items per category.

[image]

For each item set, you can specify what champions and maps it appears on, or set them to appear globally.

[image]

In-game, you click on the Recommended tab to access a drop-down list which will have all the item sets available to that champion for that map.

[image]

If you specify an item set to be specific to a champion, it will default to that item set when you first visit the shop.  Once in-game, if you select an item set through the shop, it saves that item set selection in `Config/game.cfg` under [RecommendedItems], and the next time you play that champion on that map it will show the item set by default.

The item sets are currently stored client-side in `RADS/projects/lol_air_client/releases/*highestVersionNumber*/deploy/bin/preferences/*username*.properties`.  If you play on multiple computers, simply copy this file to copy your item sets.

They have plans to move them sever-side in the future, so you will eventually have access to them from any computer.  They've also hinted that they may be adding import/export functionality, to share your item sets more easily.

Comment: Perfect, pictures and everything. +1 :)

Answer (score 8):

<strike>There is no official support for changing your recommended items. However, several users have created workarounds through 3rd party programs to accomplish this.</strike>

I've used the one linked [here](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=145862) with success, and it gets updated frequently enough and typically within a few days after patching. If you don't like that specific one, there's quite a few others floating around on the official League of Legends forums, as well as various other wiki sites.

I provide the link and echo the author with saying that using 3rd party programs to modify game files is to be done at your own risk, and there's no guarantee that this or any particular "mod" will be forever supported.

In response to your second question regarding multiple builds, at the moment there is no current way to setup different build layouts, as the recommended items tab is limited to 6 slots and 1 per character as per the game files.

Edit: This answer is no longer accurate. See [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/117723/414) for an up to date solution.

Comment: Is it also possible without using any 3rd party programs, by manually editing some game-files (*.ini)?

Comment: @F.S. I would imagine that these programs are simply doing the editing of files in the folders. Given that you're not actually recompiling the game, this must be stored in an external file somewhere. However, I do not know which files these are nor what format they're required to be in, so I cannot say for sure where or how.

Comment: Just a note that this program appears to have been broken with the Season 3 Update. An alternative is [Enigma's Item Changer](http://enigmablade.net/lol-item-changer/).

Comment: Also the API used by these tools IS an official feature that Riot put into the game to allow users to change their item recommendations; they just don't have a tool of their own to use for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to use 3rd party program, here is pretty nice manual for it: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Recommended_item_code